# In Kotlin, how do I pass a parameter so that the async scope will conserve it?

Tags: kotlin, scope, closures, coroutine

I have the following code snippet using Kotlin Coroutines

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
  println("test")

  var seed = 3
  val deferredResult = async(CommonPool){
    seed * 2
  }

  seed = 4

  runBlocking(CommonPool) {
    val result = deferredResult.await()
    println("Result is $result")
  }

  println("end")
}
```

I was expecting it to behave like javascript and conserve the value of the `seed` variable (use a copy) at the time of defining the coroutine. But instead of printing `Result is 6`, it prints `Result is 8`.

What can I do to ensure that the original value of the seed variable (which is 3) is used inside the async scope (instead of 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let see a non multi-threads example that will makes it more clearly:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    println("test")

    var seed = 3 // @1. initializing seed=3
    val deferredResult = {
        seed * 2 // @4. seed=4 then 
    }

    seed = 4  // @2. reassign seed=4

    //            v--- @3. calculates the result
    val result = deferredResult()
    //    ^---  8
    println("Result is $result");
}
```

as you can see the sequence starts `@` above that described in non multi-threads clearly the lambda is invoked lazily. which means the body of the lambda is not invoked unless the caller invoke it.

the result is uncertain in multi-threads, it maybe `6` or `8`, because it depends on whether it is the sequence `@2` or the sequence `@4` is first invoked. when we call *`async(..)`* to start a thread in pool it will take a few time, the current thread does not blocking until the thread is running.

it also has problem in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), for example:

```
var seed = 3

function deferredResult() {
    return seed * 2
}

seed = 4

var result = deferredResult()
console.log("Result is " + result);// result is also 8
```

it is solved by introduce another calls inline anonymous function in javascript. you can also solve it in kotlin by using lambda like as in javascript:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("test")

    var seed = 3
    //                    v--- like as javascript (function(seed){...})(seed);
    val deferredResult = ({ seed: Int ->
        async(CommonPool) {
            seed * 2
        }
    })(seed);

    seed = 4

    runBlocking(CommonPool) {
        val result = deferredResult.await()
        //   ^--- result is always 6 now
        println("Result is $result")
    }

    println("end")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @holi-java. I do understand what's happening here. What I'm more interested is in knowing how to ensure that the seed variable's value (3) is conserved when the coroutine is executed. (Much like closures in javascript) I've edited the question to convey my intentions more clearly

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `var`, especially in the code that involves any forms of concurrency (coroutines, threads, or even capturing values into lambdas).

In your particular example, you should declare `seed` as `val` (immutable) to prevent an accidental mistake of changing it later. In fact, the compiler should have warned you that you are capturing a mutable variable into a coroutine, but this feature is not currently implemented. See the ticket [KT-15515](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15514).

Comment: This answer was actually very helpful to fix a problem in my code where an integer has been captured by reference and I wanted it to be captured by value. So I made a val copy of it.